Is there a Dehn-like presentation of a knot quandle?
The knot group can be presented using either a Wirtinger presentation (with generators corresponding to arcs of the knot diagram) or a Dehn presentation (with generators corresponding to regions of the knot diagram). For a knot quandle, the typical presentation is Wirtinger-like, with generators corresponding to arcs.
Is there an analogous Dehn-like presentation for a knot quandle, where the generators correspond to regions of a knot diagram instead of arcs?

I don't think about quandles much at all, but I would think the answer should be yes.  If you think of the Dehn presentation as the dual 2-skeleton to the standard polyhedral decomposition of the knot exterior (the first step in the Thurston triangulation algorithm), you get a bunch of generators related by conjugation.  That looks like something that could be put into quandle language.

This account generating answer in very quick response, and very different topic. This account seems to be very suspicious.

@Ryan Budney, Thank you, this is a valuable comment! I'll try to work it out.

@D.S. Agree about the raft of suspicious answers, but this one could be legit, so I'm reposting in case it actually is useful.

Reposting an answer from a deleted account:

Yes, there is an analogous Dehn-like presentation for knot quandles where generators correspond to regions of a knot diagram instead of arcs. This structure is called a "biquasile" and was introduced by Needell and Nelson in their paper “Biquasiles and Dual Graph Diagrams".
A biquasile is defined on a set $X$ with two binary operations $*$ and $\cdot$, each defining a quasigroup structure on $X$. The key idea is to associate biquasile elements with regions of a knot diagram, rather than arcs.
The biquasile axioms are motivated by the Reidemeister moves on dual graph diagrams. For all $a,b,x,y \in X$, we have:
$$a * (x \cdot [y * (a \cdot b)]) = (a * [x \cdot y]) * (x \cdot [y * ([a * (x \cdot y)] \cdot b)])$$
$$y * ([a * (x \cdot y)] \cdot b) = (y * [a \cdot b]) * ([a * (x \cdot [y * (a \cdot b)])] \cdot b)$$
These axioms ensure that biquasile colorings of dual graph diagrams are preserved under Reidemeister moves.
The fundamental biquasile of a knot or link $L$ is defined using a presentation $\langle X | R \rangle$, where $X$ is the set of regions in a diagram of $L$, and $R$ contains relations of the form:
$$\begin{cases}
z = x * (b \cdot a) \\
x = z * (b \cdot a)
\end{cases}$$
for each crossing in the dual graph diagram, where $x$, $z$ are opposite regions at the crossing, and $a$, $b$ are the other two adjacent regions.
An important example is the Alexander biquasile, defined on an $L$-module $X$ where $L = \mathbb{Z}[d^{\pm1}, n^{\pm1}, s^{\pm1}]$, with operations:
$$x * y = (-dsn^2)x + ny \quad \text{and} \quad x \cdot y = dx + sy$$
This structure generalizes the Dehn presentation of the knot group in a way analogous to how quandles generalize the Wirtinger presentation.
